# Is there a geometrical interpretation of diagonalization and change of basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are square matrices of size n, defining $T:V\rightarrow W$.

We know the definition,  $A$ and $B$ are similar if and only if there exists a non-singular matrix $P$ such that $B=P^{-1}AP$. From my previous studies, I was told that $P$ is the change of basis matrix from the standard basis, $\beta$ to basis $\zeta$ in vector space $V$. (Is this true? Why?)

We can extend further the definition of similarity for transformations $T$ with n linearly independent eigenvectors. $A$ is diagonalizable if and only if there exists a non-singular matrix $P$ such that $D=P^{-1}AP$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix (or $A$ is similar to a diagonal matrix $D$ ). Again, $P$ is the change of basis matrix from the standard basis, $\beta$ to basis $\zeta$ in vector space $V$.

I am attempting to understand diagonalization in terms of a change of basis, geometrically. The motivation to study this is that I am trying to understand the **differences** between Singular Value Decomposition(SVD) and Eigenvalue Decomposition(more specifically Diagonalization).

So this is as far as I understand diagonalization in terms of change of basis.

$$x=Px^{\prime} $$ 
$$y=Py^{\prime} $$

where $Ax=y$, hence $x\in V$ and $y\in W$ and $P:V_{\beta} \rightarrow V_{\zeta}$

$$y=Ax\implies APx^{\prime}=Py^{\prime}\implies  P^{-1}APx^{\prime}=y^{\prime}$$

What I understand is that I can use a diagonal matrix $P^{-1}AP$ and the coordinate  $x^{\prime}$ to get a corresponding coordinate for  $y^{\prime}$ and vice versa. More simply, I can define the transformation in terms of the $\zeta$ basis as oppose to the standard basis $\beta$. ( I may have actually answered my question by writing this out).

We can also perform the same illustration for SVD. Suppose $V$ and $U$ is the change of basis matrix for the domain space and range space respectively.

$$x=Vx^{\prime}$$
$$y=Uy^{\prime}$$

where $Ax=y$, hence $x\in V$ and $y\in W$, $V:V_{\beta} \rightarrow V_{\zeta}$ and $U:W_{\beta} \rightarrow W_{\zeta}$

$$y=Ax= AVx^{\prime} \implies y^{\prime}=U^{H}y=U^{H}AVx^{\prime}$$

But is there a sound geometric illustration of diagonalization and the SVD by looking into the change of basis?

Comment: At a particular case, many references seem to explain the geometric interpretation of SVD as the relationship between basis vectors v i   and u i   by Av i =σ i u i  . A  is a 3×2  matrix and is of full rank 2 . If the domain space is imagined as a 2 dimensional circle then the range space will be that of an ellipsoid. The transformation demonstrates that the basis vectors are rotated and stretched by a scalar multiple of σ i

Comment: I now consider my question quite ambiguous as to what a geometrical interpretation means. I think the example above does not represent exactly what I was thinking of (I wanted to know how the $ \Sigma  $ transformed the domain space). I have still not resolved it. But, if we use the sort of idea above, $Av_{i }=\lambda v_{ i} $ , we can imagine a circle transforming into an ellipsoid.(without rotation and stretched) (given eigenvectors chosen are orthogonal)